# Combinatorial proof of binary partition function $b(n)$ is always even

Tags: binary, integer-partitions, combinatorial-proofs, congruence-relations

For all integer $n$, let $b(n)$ be the number of partition of $n$ into power of two.
For instance, $b(4)=4$, since
\begin{align*}
4 &= 2^2 \\
&= 2^1+2^1 \\
&= 2^1+2^0+2^0 \\
&= 2^0+2^0+2^0+2^0.
\end{align*}

I want to show the congruence $b(n) \equiv 0 \pmod 2$ for all $n \ge 2$ using combinatorial proof.
Recently, I have proved this congruence by strong induction on $n$. But, I want to know about the combinatorial proof of this congruence, that is, using some rules or a bijection between partition to other partition.

But, I didn't have any idea to show it.

What I tried is as follows.

I was thinking for a rule that we should divide each binary partition of $n$ into two classes/sets with the same cardinality based on whether it contains $2^0$ or not. For example, consider $n=2,3,4,5$.
The binary partition of them, respectively, are
$$2^1, 2^0+2^0,$$
$$2^1+2^0, 2^0+2^0+2^0,$$
$$2^2,2^1+2^1,2^1+2^0+2^0,2^0+2^0+2^0+2^0,$$
and
$$2^2+2^0,2^1+2^1+2^0,2^1+2^0+2^0+2^0,2^0+2^0+2^0+2^0+2^0.$$

We can divide each binary partitions of $2$ into two sets,
namely, $A=\{2^1\}$ and $B=\{2^0+2^0\}$. Similarly for $n=3,4,$ and $n=5$.
But, for $n=6$, this rule didn't work, since
\begin{align*}
6 &= 2^2+2^1 \\
&= 2^2+2^0+2^0 \\
&= 2^1+2^1+2^1 \\
&= 2^1+2^1+2^0+2^0 \\
&= 2^1+2^0+2^0+2^0+2^0 \\
&= 2^0+2^0+2^0+2^0+2^0+2^0.
\end{align*}

If we apply the same rule as above, we must have that all binary partitions of $6$ divided to two sets, namely,
$$A=\{2^2+2^1,2^1+2^1+2^1\}$$ and
$$B=\{2^2+2^0+2^0,2^1+2^1+2^0+2^0,2^1+2^0+2^0+2^0+2^0,2^0+2^0+2^0+2^0+2^0+2^0\}.$$
But then, $|A|=2\ne 4 =|B|$.

Any idea please? I really need an insight about this rule to show the congruence of $b(n)$.
Many thanks in advanced.

Comment: Have you considered partitions based on number of elements?

Comment: Like, even number of terms in the sum vs odd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A$ be the set of partitions with an even number of parts and $B$ the set of partitions with an odd number of parts. Consider the function $f:A\to B$ which sends a partition $p = [2^{a_1},\dots,2^{a_k}]$ where $a_1 \leq a_2 \leq \dots \leq a_k$ to

$$p'=\begin{cases} [2^{a_1},\dots, 2^{a_k-1}, 2^{a_k - 1}], \text{ if } a_k\neq a_{k-1} \\
[2^{a_1}, \dots, 2^{a_{k-2}}, 2^{a_k+1}], \,\text{ if } a_k = a_{k-1}\end{cases}$$

It's easy to see that when defined that way, $f$ is bijective, so $|A|=|B|$. But $b(n) = |A|+|B| \equiv 0 \pmod{2}$.

Comment: @sqrtpi Why don't you try to apply this idea in the examples you provided? For example, when $n=6$, $2^2+2^1$ will get mapped to $2^1+2^1+2^1$ because the highest power of $2$ appears only once, while $2^1+2^1+2^1+2^1$ will get mapped to $2^2+2^1+2^1$ because the highest power of $2$ appears more than once.

Comment: @sqrtpi No, in that case, we just split the highest power $2^{a_k}$ to $2^{a_k - 1} + 2^{a_k - 1}$ and we keep all the rest the same.

Comment: @sqrtpi For example, $6=2^2+2^1 = (2^1 + 2^1) + 2^1$.

Comment: Aaaah I see. My bad. Thanks for the idea, Sir. I want to show it now using your idea. I'll be back to you later and asking for the correct proof of my own. Many thanks in advanced.